# Using xpath to extract hreflang URL

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I'm just really struggling with `xPath`. I've read a couple of guides and I just can't seem to get this right.

Basically, I want to extract all `URLs` that contain `"/ro_ro/"`.

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/pl_pl/" hreflang="pl-PL"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/pt_br/" hreflang="pt-BR"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/pt_pt/" hreflang="pt-PT"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/ro_ro/" hreflang="ro-RO"> 
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/fi_fi/" hreflang="fi-FI">
```

Ideally, the `xpath` query would return: https://www.stackoverflow.com/ro_ro/.

I've got close, but there are multiple links on the page to the same `URL`, but never with `hreflang` attribute.

I am to do this on a mass scale, I should note that this means deep page URLs that i want to extract will look like: https://www.stackoverflow.com/ro_ro/xpath-help-for-a-noob/

Edit: Any ideas why this got downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `XPath` to get desired `href` from `link` element that contains `hreflang` attribute:

```
//link[@hreflang and contains(@href, 'ro_ro')]/@href
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! That didn't seem to work for me though. Any ideas?

Comment: What you mean `didn't seem to work for me`? You get incorrect output or you get error? This is pure `XPath` solution while tool you use might not support it...

Comment: Hi Andersson, sorry my mistake, it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your issue. Thanks

Comment: Should be //link[@hreflang and contains(@hreflang, 'ro_ro')]/@href

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hreflang in Google Spreadsheet using the following formula

```
=importxml("https://example.org" ,"//link[@hreflang]/@href")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to get those urls with the statement

```
descendant::link[contains(@href, 'ro_ro')]
```

with the base node of the document as the current node

the descendant axis tells xpath to look through all child nodes. ::link means to only select the nodes with the name link and the expression within square brackets means "select only those nodes, whose href attribute contains 'ro_ro'-